# Strange behaviour of key /pgfplots/ymax

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,ymax=3e7]
      \addplot {1000000*x^2} node {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}};
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxexponent}{round(log10(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}))}
      \node at (axis cs:0,1.5e7) {\maxexponent};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that gives the correct result

[image]

But if I remove the `ymax` specification in `axis` environment the `addplot` node still works correctly but I get an error in defining the `\maxexponent` macro:

```
! FP error: Logarithm of zero!.
```

and the node at the center becomes `0.0`.

Why this different behaviour of the key `/pgplots/ymax`? (**answered in Jake comment**)

### Edit

I asked this because I want to use the `ymax` value automatically determined by `pgfplots`. So I update my question to this one: "How can I record the value of `ymax` to use it in the same `axis` environment (from Jake comment I don't think this is possible) or in a subsequent one?"

Comment: Unless you specify `ymax` explicitly, PGFPlots can't know its value until all the plots have been specified: It is an axis-wide property, after all, and later plots could still change the axis limits. The `node` works because it isn't actually typeset when you call it, but rather the typesetting is deferred until the very end of the axis environment. That would be the answer to your question, but I guess you don't want to know "why", but rather you're trying to accomplish something, right? If you edit your question to explain what you're trying to do, there might be a more satisfying answer

Comment: @Jake you're right, I don't want only to know why :-) but also the motivation of this behaviour is interesting. I edited my question

Comment: If your use case is to use that number for nodes etc. you can squeeze it in `after end axis` (or something named similar) then it would be available But not when pgfplots is collecting the plots. It quite doesn't work like TikZ i.e. path after path... See Christian's comment here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99922/automatically-choosing-preset-color-schemes-in-pgfplots-based-on-number-of-entri

Comment: @percusse `after end axis` is just what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @percusse Does your comment here constitute an answer?

Comment: @percusse Can you answer?

Comment: @egreg Sorry, added the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` is built on TikZ/PGF however it spends tremendous effort before it leaves the drawing the PDF path drawing objects to PGF. Hence it needs to first collect the plots, process them, see if they are such and such, how much space it would need, what's the highest and lowest points so that automatic axis scalings are introduced etc.

Thus, when you request the `ymax` value it hasn't decided yet and by default it is zero. Hence log of zero causes the error.

Since you only need to use the value and not something complicated you can just ask for the value when PGFPlots is done with the axis creation. And that (roughly speaking) corresponds to the point `after end axis` options are evaluated. So your code can be modified as follows

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
    \begin{axis}[clip=false,
                 after end axis/.code={
                  \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxexponent}{round(log10(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}))}
                  \node[left] at (a) {\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci precision=3]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}};
                  \node at (axis cs:0,1.5e7) {\maxexponent};
                }
                ]
      \addplot {1000000*x^2} coordinate (a);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]