# pgfplots: unable to affect cycle list name while using \pgfplotsinvokeforeach

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am unable to use custom colors from  `cycle list name` with `pgfplotsinvokeforeach`. Some pointers could be gauged from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99922/automatically-choosing-preset-color-schemes-in-pgfplots-based-on-number-of-entri) post, which discusses execution of various steps in a plot function.

In the MWE below, I am trying to segregate the bar chart into two categories where the numeric values are greater than median and other as less than the median value.

I use the `x` value range as input for `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and  `restrict x to domain` to `#1` values

> From page 88, section 4.6.6 of pgfplots manual
>
> `/pgfplots/cycle list name={<macro>}`
>
> ...the currently active cycle list will be used if you write either
>   `\addplot+[<keys>]` ...; or if you ***don't*** use square brackets as in >`\addplot[<explicit plot specication>]`

The `cycle list name` functionality does not function possibly because I am specifying `restrict x to domain` parameter explicitly to `\addplot` function.

**Code:**

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\tick},scaled x ticks=false}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}


\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,34,68}
\definecolor{ochre}{RGB}{255,161,0}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{customcol}{%
{fill=darkblue, draw=black},
{fill=ochre, draw=black}
}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
number,label
0.031,A
0.038,B
0.043,C
0.046,D
0.056,E
0.063,F
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
      cycle list name=customcol,
      width=5in,
      symbolic y  coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
      tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
      label style={font=\footnotesize},
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      yticklabel style={text width=3cm, align=right,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
      xbar=5pt,
      bar width=4pt,
      point meta=x*100,
      xlabel=number,
      ylabel=label,
      y tick label style={text width=0.5cm,align=center},
      xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%,
      xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\%$},
      every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\footnotesize,
                /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                anchor=180
                }
    ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0:0.041,0.041:0.0693}{
    \addplot +[restrict x to domain=#1] table {\data};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Possible Solutions**

The syntax below is not 100% correct but wanted to illustrate the thought process:

Is there a way to create a list such as `{[partition1,color1],[partition2,color2]}`
which is input to `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` and `#1` to be resolved as

`\addplot [color1] +[restrict x to domain=[partition1] table {\data};`

**Output:**

[image: bar plot]

**Addendum**

1)The node labels are of same color as that of individual bar, this could be unreadable with certain colors. Is there a way to enforce a common color to all node labels, say black.

2) The y tick label alignment is a bit off, for category 1 the tick labels are **below** the bars and for category 2 the tick labels are **above** the bars

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here: `cycle list name` is the right way to approach this, and the cycle list will be respected as long as you use `\addplot +[...]`. However, you need to use `cycle list name` *after* `ybar`, since `ybar` sets its own list.

Furthermore, you need to make sure to either put a `%` after the last entry in the cycle list, or to put the closing `}` directly behind it (not on a new line).

To get black labels, add `black` to the `every node near coord` style.

To align the bars with the tick marks, set `ybar=0pt, bar shift=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\tick},scaled x ticks=false}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}


\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,34,68}
\definecolor{ochre}{RGB}{255,161,0}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{customcol}{%
{fill=darkblue, color=red, draw=black},
{fill=ochre, draw=black}%
}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=true]{
number,label
0.031,A
0.038,B
0.043,C
0.046,D
0.056,E
0.063,F
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
      width=5in,
      symbolic y  coords={A,B,C,D,E,F},
      tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
      label style={font=\footnotesize},
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      yticklabel style={text width=3cm, align=right,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
      xbar=0pt,
      bar shift=0pt,
      bar width=4pt,
      point meta=x*100,
      xlabel=number,
      ylabel=label,
      y tick label style={text width=0.5cm,align=center},
      xticklabel=\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\,\%,
      xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}$\%$},
      every node near coord/.append style={
                black,
                font=\footnotesize,
                /pgf/number format/precision=3,
                anchor=180
                },
      cycle list name=customcol
    ]
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0:0.041,0.041:0.0693}{
    \addplot +[restrict x to domain=#1] table {\data};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```